# Python async function

Tags: python, python-3.x, асинхронность

3дрaвствyйте, начал читать про асинхронность, но возник вопрос.

В первом случаем мне нужно запустить 2 цикла в разных потоках, во втором нужно получить `return` асинхронной функции.

```py
import asyncio

async def test():
    while True:
        print(0)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    asyncio.ensure_future(test())
    while True:
        print(1)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Код выше запустит 2 цикла в разных потоках, но через `asyncio.ensure_future()` нельзя получить `return`, то есть следующий код не сработает.

```py
import asyncio

async def test():
    return 1

async def main():
    print( asyncio.ensure_future(test()))
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Поэтому я ищу функцию которая сможет запустить функцию в отдельном потоке, как `asyncio.ensure_future()` но что бы можно было получить `return` от функции

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы получить результат работы асинхронной функции, используйте `await`:

```py
async def main():
    print(await asyncio.ensure_future(test()))
          ^^^^^
```

Вывод:

```
1
```

Вы получаете из асинхронной функции задачу `Task`, чтобы дождаться результата её работы и получить результат нужен `await`.

Вы так и делаете в первом примере кода, просто вас там не интересует результат работы функций, а только их завершение. Но `await` используется в обоих случаях - и когда нужно просто вызвать асинхронную функцию, и когда от неё нужно получить результат.

P.S. Попробовал в Google Colab, а вроде даже и так работает:

```py
print(await test())
```

Comment: А можно запустить асихронную функцию без `asyncio.ensure_future()`? Как-нибудь через `await`, более красиво.

Comment: @Cergey2202 Я в питоне не очень хорошо знаю асинхронность. И она тут достигается с помощью сторонних библиотек, из-за этого так всё коряво. В `C#` то к примеру да, можно было бы просто написать `await test()` и всё, а тут как-то всё хитро. Так что не подскажу как тут проще сделать.

Comment: Хм, я сейчас попробовал, вроде и просто `await test()` работает )))

Comment: Да, `await test()` сработает, и вернёт `return`, но проблема в том что что тогда функция будет запущена в текущем потоке.

Comment: Ох сложно всё. В `C#` всё как-то проще. Там и многопоточность нормальная и асинхронность.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь